# File compression and log rotation

Tags: bash-completion

I have a usecase to compress 5 days of log files and then delete 7 days data. My folder structure is as  /user/var/logs/fw/2024-01.01/01.log.

At the moment I have a cron which is rotating the logs after 7 days. But my requirement is to keep compressed data for 5 days and 2 days of uncompressed data.
I want to compress and store the the compressed files in a different folder like  /
**/user/var/backup-logs/fw/2024-01-01.tar.gz.**
Can some suggest something regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: Please check your tags: [tag:bash-completion] seems to be completely off. Also, this sounds related to server configuration, not programming: Please see [Which computer science / programing Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/364505) (as well as [help/on-topic] for stackoverflow)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.